# HTML/Javascript submenu?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, submenu

This image illustrates best what i want:
[image: submenu]

I have a standard HTML page which is interacting with a mysql database. One of of my pages, i want to have sub menus which load info ajaxly based on a tab (not refreshing the whole page).
I don't want to reinvent the wheel...as this has been done so many times before.
Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: is the content in the boxes changing? if not, don't do ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the onClick event of the tabs, use jQuery to make an Ajax call (with get/post arguments) to get the content you need from the server.